# When i test api gateway for post method " Endpoint response body before transformations: null " why

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda, api-gateway

testing post methord from apigateway returns null to lambda function ,but if value directly added to bodymapping template lambda work properly

if add texting code directly as gateway body mapping template ,then lambda works fine.

how to properly pass value from test to mapping template

Answer (score 0):

```js
  #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  

  "id": "$inputRoot.id",
   "res": "$inputRoot.res",
    "rate": "$inputRoot.rate",
     "index": "$inputRoot.index"
}
```

problem solved,all data called after make it an object as $inputroot